# Compare sql table with txt file line by line with table if variable dosent exsit insert it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, requirements.txt

```
<?php
function db_query()
    {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "single4thenight";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "SELECT id, name, alias, type, parent, ordering, published FROM iutca_jomcl_locations";  //selects locations from 
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "  alias" . $row["alias"]. "  type: " . $row["type"]. " - parent: " . $row["parent"]. " ordering " . $row["ordering"]. "published " . $row["published"]."<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();

    }
function read_location()
    {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "single4thenight";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "SELECT name FROM iutca_jomcl_locations";  //selects locations from 
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //  echo "Location : " . $row["name"]."<br>";
                $row_name = $row["name"];
                echo $row_name.'<br />';
            }

        }
        $file1 = "./location.txt";
        $lines = file($file1);
        foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
        {
        echo $line;

        }

    }
```

My location.txt file contains this

Auburn
Birmingham
Dothan
Gadsden
Huntsville
Mobile
Montgomery
Muscle Shoals
Tuscaloosa

I would like to compare my sql database with txt file to make sure that i do not arealdy have variables inside. I do not want to put duplicates in side my sql i would like to know what is the easiest way to update my sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead of just `INSERT INTO` and MySQL will then ignore duplicate entries. See the [MySQL documentation for INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) for more information. So, based on what I see in your question, your SQL would look something like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO iutca_jomcl_locations ('name') values (?)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I Used This and it Helped and Work Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First we read file content to the `$content` variable

```
$content = file('mytxt.txt')
```

As you posted, your file contains words separated with space (if not, skip this and make variable $words contain values you need) so we need to split content, to get each word as array item

```
$words = explode(" ", $content);
```

Finally, inserting value and checking if there is one like that existing in DB

```
foreach($words as $word)
{
  $sql = "INSERT  iutca_jomcl_locations (name) 
  SELECT  $word
  WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
          (   SELECT  1
              FROM    tblSoftwareTitles 
              WHERE   name = $word
          );"
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

`iutca_jomcl_locations` - table name
`name` - column to insert (also checking for unique values using this column)

Answer (score 0):

I used This Code and it Worked for me

```
 foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
        {
            $line = $line;
            //echo $line;
            $sql = "SELECT ordering, name FROM iutca_jomcl_locations WHERE name='$line'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
        echo "Found Locations: " . $row["name"]." The ordering Number Is " . $row["ordering"]."<br>";
        $ordering =$row["ordering"];
        }
        } else {

                if($ordering >=0)
                {
                    $count = $ordering;
                    //echo "0 results";
                    $lowerCase = strtolower($line);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO iutca_jomcl_locations (name, alias , parent, published,ordering)
                    VALUES ('$line','$lowerCase','$parent','1','$count')";


                    $count = $count + 1;
                    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "New record created successfully <br />";
                    } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                    }
                }
        }

        }
```